# What is wrong with Modulo with Double to find the digits of a number?

Tags: java, double, modulo

I am trying to find the number of a digits in a long double that an int can't hold. It takes the user's inputted number and finds the digits of it and puts it into an int array. It seems to work perfectly fine with smaller numbers such as <10^10 but when it approaches larger numbers the last few digits seems to be off.

Take a look at my function please:

```
static void insertDigits(int[] digits, double number) {
    double num=number;
    int counter=digits(number)-1;
    while(counter>=0) {
        digits[counter]=(int) (num%10);
        num=Math.floor(num/10);
        counter=counter-1;
    }
}
```

When I input 13256709, I get(good):
1.3256709E7  1
1.3256709E7  3
1.3256709E7  2
1.3256709E7  5
1.3256709E7  6
1.3256709E7  7
1.3256709E7  0
1.3256709E7  9
But when I input a long number such as 25768437216701562, I get:
2.576843721670156E16  2
2.576843721670156E16  5
2.576843721670156E16  7
2.576843721670156E16  6
2.576843721670156E16  8
2.576843721670156E16  4
2.576843721670156E16  3
2.576843721670156E16  7
2.576843721670156E16  2
2.576843721670156E16  1
2.576843721670156E16  6
2.576843721670156E16  7
2.576843721670156E16  0
2.576843721670156E16  1
2.576843721670156E16  5
2.576843721670156E16  6
2.576843721670156E16  0
As you can see the last digit is off. Would be happy to send more code if needed if there is there is another problem with part of the code. I feel like it has something to do with the modulo operator being funky with doubles. Thanks for any help!

Comment: "I feel like it has something to do with the modulo operator being funky with doubles." It very much is. try `1 % 0.1`

Comment: No, I get 0. But another thing I found was that 25768437216701562 I don't get the last 2 digits but 25768437216701564 works fine.

Comment: The previous representable value to 25768437216701564 is 25768437216701560, you can't represent 25768437216701562 as a double

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach won't work with `double` as the accumulated rounding error will leave you with a few digits off. To convert a double without losing precision, you have to use integer arithmetic exclusively. i.e. Use `Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d)` and work from there using the IEEE-754 format.

Here is an example I wrote earlier.  https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/BytesInternal.java#L1513

> But when I input a long number such as 25768437216701562, I get: 2.576843721670156E16

This is because 2.576843721670156E16 is the closest representable value, next value after that is 2.5768437216701564E16

You can see this with the following which takes the 64-bit floating as if it was a 64-bit long.

```
System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(25768437216701560.0));
System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(25768437216701564.0));
```

prints

```
4852315308354829086
4852315308354829087
```

just as there is no long representation between these two long values, there is no double representation between them either.

Comment: Sorry but would you mind explaining in a little bit more detail. I searched up .doubleToRawLongBits but I don't really understand

Comment: @EdwardChen I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format from that you can decode the exact representable value, but also it helps to understand it's limitations.

Comment: Is there a data type I can use that will work for all numbers 10^50 and lower? Or is using Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) and IEEE-754 the only way because that method seems a little complex.

Comment: @EdwardChen it is complex, but floating point fundamentally has accumulated representation errors for a division. You could use an 80-bit `long double` in C++, but Java doesn't have that. If you want simplicity, use `Double.toString(d)` or `DecimalFormat`

Comment: and when I do System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(25768437216701561.0)); I get the same as System.out.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(25768437216701560.0)); so basically how do I use .doubletoRawLongBits?

Comment: oh ok Ill take a look into that; I didn't see ur response

Comment: @EdwardChen you use the function to see if two numbers are basically the same so there is no way to tell them apart. You can also it them for decoding the exact value but as you mention, this might be needlessly complicated.

Comment: Ok so I found another method of just having insertDigits accepting an int array and  a long instead of a double. This seems to help so that 25768437216701563 and 25768437216701561 actually give me those digits. Just wondering, is there a problem I will encounter if I do this and are there any limitation as I go higher to this?

Comment: Ok sorry for all of the problems but I found out then when I changed it to a long and user a scanner for scan.nextLong, the number 2576843721670156209878907654568790890 gives me an inputmismatchexception even though a long can hold 2^63-1 why is that?

Comment: @EdwardChen that number is 2.793819561190416E17 times Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @EdwardChen are you sure you don't want to use BigDecimal or BigInteger for large numbers?

Comment: I want to but I am not totally sure how to write the function. So basically I am dealing with only integers so I'll only need to use bigInteger right? Also BigInteger is just a bigger data holder and is a class with diff methods right? Sorry, I am pretty new into the topic.Thanks.

Comment: do you think it can handle all the numbers to 10^50?

Comment: oh and sorry for all the comments but I 64 bits isnt enough for 10^50 right? I was readhing this https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-initialize-BigInteger-value-in-java-as-I-can-do-int-x-0-in-c and I think I have to use the second option where I pass a numeric string. Is that the .doubleToRawLongBits you were talking about earlier? Thanks once again for all the help!

Comment: nevermnind my last comments lol... I watched some good videos on it and learned more about it. The only question I have now is: How do I take a bigInteger as an input from a console(preferably) or .txtfile as input? I can only see using a double or long input from a scanner and then making it into a biginteger which wont work I believe

Comment: @EdwardChen read it as a string e.g. `new BigInteger(scanner.next())`

Comment: @EdwardChen double gives you about 15 digits of accuracy, BigInteger gives you up to 2^31-1 digits.